# Null check operator used on a null value even when the value is not null

Tags: flutter

I can't insert my data inside my database even when I have already used controller. It still shows this error

> The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
> Null check operator used on a null value

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:testerlogin/models/flowerbook.dart';
import 'package:testerlogin/models/user.dart';
import '../common_widgets/buttons.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import '../common_widgets/checkbox.dart';

class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FormPage({Key? key, required this.user}) : super(key: key);
  final User user;
  @override
  State<FormPage> createState() => _FormPageState();
}

class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();
  String selectedValue = 'Bouquet';

  final dateController = TextEditingController();
  final checkboxController = TextEditingController();
  final dropdownController = TextEditingController();

  final TextStyle labelStyle = const TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
  );

  final TextStyle inputStyle = const TextStyle(
    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                //Spacing
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 25,
                ),

                //Back Button
                Container(
                  height: 50,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(2 * 16, 0, 2 * 16, 0),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                const SizedBox(
                  height: 25,
                ),

                SizedBox(
                  width: screenWidth,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(3 * 16, 0, 3 * 16, 3 * 16),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        //Checkbox

                        FormField(builder: (FormFieldState state) {
                          return InputDecorator(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: "Delivery Date",
                                labelStyle: labelStyle,
                                errorText: state.errorText,
                                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                                floatingLabelBehavior:
                                    FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                              ),
                              child: FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
                                controller: dateController,
                                name: "delivery_date",
                              ));
                        }),

                        const SizedBox(height: 25),

                        FormField(
                          builder: (FormFieldState state) {
                            return InputDecorator(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: "Flower Type",
                                labelStyle: labelStyle,
                                errorText: state.errorText,
                                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                                floatingLabelBehavior:
                                    FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  checkItemBuilder(context, "Roses",
                                      checkboxController: checkboxController),
                                  checkItemBuilder(context, "Tulips",
                                      checkboxController: checkboxController),
                                  checkItemBuilder(context, "Carnation",
                                      checkboxController: checkboxController),
                                  checkItemBuilder(context, "Daisies",
                                      checkboxController: checkboxController),
                                  checkItemBuilder(context, "Tulips",
                                      checkboxController: checkboxController),
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),

                        const SizedBox(height: 25),

                        SizedBox(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child: FormField(
                            builder: (FormFieldState state) {
                              return InputDecorator(
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  labelText: "Arrangement",
                                  labelStyle: labelStyle,
                                  errorText: state.errorText,
                                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                                  floatingLabelBehavior:
                                      FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
                                ),
                                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                  value: selectedValue,
                                  isExpanded: true,
                                  onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      selectedValue = newValue ?? 'Bouquet';
                                      dropdownController.text = selectedValue;
                                    });
                                  },
                                  items: <String>[
                                    'Bouquet',
                                    'Vase',
                                    'Box',
                                    'Basket'
                                  ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                                      (String value) {
                                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      value: value,
                                      child: Text(value),
                                    );
                                  }).toList(),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),

                        const SizedBox(height: 25),

                        //Submit Button
                        ButtonGradient(
                          label: 'Submit',
                          textStyle: const TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: 50,
                          gradientColor: const [
                            Colors.purpleAccent,
                            Colors.deepPurple,
                          ],
                          onPressed: () {
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              Flowerbook flowerbook = Flowerbook(
                                deliver_date: dateController.text,
                                flower_type: checkboxController.text,
                                arrangement: dropdownController.text,
                                user_id: widget.user.user_id,
                              );

                              Flowerbook.register(flowerbook);
                            }
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think something is wrong around here:

```
 onPressed: () {
                            if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                              Flowerbook flowerbook = Flowerbook(
                                deliver_date: dateController.text,
                                flower_type: checkboxController.text,
                                arrangement: dropdownController.text,
                                user_id: widget.user.user_id,
                              );

                              Flowerbook.register(flowerbook);
                            }
```

But it could also be at the widgets

Here is the error:

```
The following _CastError was thrown while handling a gesture:
Null check operator used on a null value

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _FormPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:testerlogin/pages/formpage.dart:187:54)
#1      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1072:21)
#2      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253:24)
#3      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:627:11)
#4      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:306:5)
#5      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:276:7)
#6      GestureArenaManager.sweep (package:flutter/src/gestures/arena.dart:163:27)
#7      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:464:20)
#8      GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:22)
#9      RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:337:11)
#10     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:395:7)
#11     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:357:5)
#12     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:314:7)
#13     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
#14     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:167:13)
#15     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:341:7)
#16     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)

Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer:
  TapGestureRecognizer#75718
```

That cannot be possible because all of the values are already inside the controller.

I tried printing out the data when I pressed submit button. But it still shows the same error, it didn't even print out the values inside the controller. So, I have removed the code. And tried other ways to fix this.

**The code should insert the values to the database after the user have filled in the form.**

Comment: The error suggests that there's a problem with your `onTap` but I don't see an `onTap` in your code. would you [edit] your question to include that?

Comment: point where the error is occured

Comment: @MendelG I have checked my code, and there is no onTap either. I don't know why in the terminal it tells that

Comment: @KrishnaAcharya I have edited the question where I pinpoint where I think the problem might occur.

Comment: @NadHam Please share the code for `Flowerbook`

Comment: Change this `final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();` to `final  _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();` and let me know the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as mentioned inthe error, on line 187

`if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {`

you're using `currentState!` (Null Check Operator) when (*evidently*) `currentState` is null.
I dont know why, but you can confirm by checking this, and handling the `null` case accordingly, or checking the rest of the code to see why it is `null` in this case.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the code. But now it different problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `Form` widget that is a child of `SingleChildScrollView` to `FormBuilder`.

check README on [flutter_form_builder package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder)